# How to synchronize sensor data with different sampling rates in octave?

Tags: signal-processing, octave, android-sensors, kalman-filter

I want to implement a kalman sensor fusion based upon accelerometer, rotation vector and WLAN. I load sensor data from CSV file for each android sensor(Accelerometer, Rotation vector and WLAN) by using dlmread. Each sensor has different sampling rates from 2ms to 200ms. My problem is that I do not know how to access the data for implementing a sensor fusion because the values are out of sync.

```matlab
accelData = dlmread("1.csv", ",", 1, 0);

accelX = accelData(:, 15);
accelY = accelData(:, 16);
accelZ = accelData(:, 17);

rotVecData = dlmread("11.csv", ",", 1, 0);

rot1 = rotVecData(:, 15);
rot2 = rotVecData(:, 16);
rot3 = rotVecData(:, 17);
rot4 = rotVecData(:, 18);
rot5 = rotVecData(:, 19);

dtA = 0.002;#2ms
samplesA = length(accelX);
tAccel = 0:dtA:(samplesA*dtA - dtA);
dtR = dtA*5;#10ms
samplesR = length(rot1);
tRot = 0:dtR:(samplesR*dtR - dtR);

for i = 1 : samplesR
  r = [rot1(i), rot2(i), rot3(i), rot4(i), rot5(i)];

  [azimuth] = Orientation(r, 90);
  a(end+1) = rad2deg(azimuth);
end

figure
plot(tAccel, accelX, tRot, rot1)
```

In the example I could plot 2 values of different sensors in correct time interval. The output is the following:
[image: plottet accelerometer and rot vector]

The problem here is that I can not iterate over the values for further calculations. Because the accel(i) value takes place with a rate of 2ms while the i-th element in rot1 has a rate of 20ms. So each sensor array from CSV has different sizes but all of them takes place in the same time interval.

In the shown figure it is correct but I do not know how to iterate over the data in one loop corresponding to the different sampling rates?

Note: The values depends on each other(Pedestrian dead reckoning based on rotation vector and accelerometer based step detection).

Comment: Have you looked at the [`resample`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/resample.html) function from the `signal` package?

Comment: Yes. I have seen that such function exists. But the documentation is really minimalistic. There is no information about the factor p/q. There are only 2 references and those are a bit of serious reading.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for the corresponding MATLAB function, it's a lot more complete: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html